# Does postgresql have a maximum number of where predicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a very long query which has over 100 predicates in WHERE clause, but when I past it into POSTGRESQL environment, it reminds some AND in where clause are missing. If I delete some predicates, the results are correct, is this because there is maximum number of AND in where clause? thanks.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
student12.id,
student11.id,
student10.id,
student9.id ,
student8.id ,
student7.id ,
student6.id ,
student5.id ,
student4.id ,
student3.id ,
student2.id ,
student1.id 
FROM
student student12,
student student11,
student student10,
student student9,
student student8,
student student7,
student student6,
student student5,
student student4,
student student3,
student student2,
student student1
WHERE
student1.id<>student12.id and
student2.id<>student3.id and 
student2.id<>student4.id and 
student2.id<>student5.id and 
student2.id<>student6.id and 
student2.id<>student7.id and 
student2.id<>student8.id and 
student2.id<>student9.id and
student2.id<>student10.id and
student2.id<>student11.id and
student2.id<>student12.id and
student3.id<>student4.id and 
student3.id<>student5.id and 
student3.id<>student6.id and 
student3.id<>student7.id and 
student3.id<>student8.id and 
student3.id<>student9.id and
student3.id<>student10.id and
student3.id<>student11.id and
student3.id<>student12.id and
student4.id<>student5.id and 
student4.id<>student6.id and 
student4.id<>student7.id and 
student4.id<>student8.id and 
student4.id<>student9.id and
student4.id<>student10.id and
student4.id<>student11.id and
student4.id<>student12.id and
student5.id<>student6.id and 
student5.id<>student7.id and 
student5.id<>student8.id and 
student5.id<>student9.id and
student5.id<>student10.id and
student5.id<>student11.id and
student5.id<>student12.id and
student6.id<>student7.id and 
student6.id<>student8.id and 
student6.id<>student9.id and
student6.id<>student10.id and
student6.id<>student11.id and
student6.id<>student12.id and
student7.id<>student8.id and 
student7.id<>student9.id and
student7.id<>student10.id and
student7.id<>student11.id and
student7.id<>student12.id and
student8.id<>student9.id and
student8.id<>student10.id and
student8.id<>student11.id and
student8.id<>student12.id and
student9.id<>student10.id and
student9.id<>student11.id and
student9.id<>student12.id and
student10.id<>student11.id and
student10.id<>student12.id and
student11.id<>student12.id and

student1.class2=student2.class2 AND
student1.class2=student3.class1 AND
student1.class2=student4.class1 AND
student1.class1=student5.class1 AND
student1.class1=student6.class1 AND
student2.class2=student3.class1 AND
student2.class2=student4.class1 AND
student2.class1=student6.class2 AND
student2.class1=student8.class2 AND
student2.class1=student10.class2 AND
student2.class1=student12.class2 AND
student3.class1=student4.class1 AND
student3.class2=student11.class1 AND
student3.class2=student12.class1 AND
student4.class2=student7.class2 AND
student4.class2=student9.class2 AND
student4.class2=student11.class2 AND
student5.class1=student6.class1 AND
student5.class2=student8.class1 AND
student6.class2=student8.class2 AND
student6.class2=student10.class2 AND
student6.class2=student12.class2 AND
student7.class2=student9.class2 AND
student7.class2=student11.class2 AND
student8.class2=student10.class2 AND
student8.class2=student12.class2 AND
student9.class2=student11.class2 AND
student10.class2=student12.class2 AND
student11.class1=student12.class1 and
student1.sex=1 AND
student2.sex=2 AND
student3.sex=1 AND
student4.sex=2 AND
student5.sex=1 AND
student6.sex=1 AND
student7.sex=1 AND
student8.sex=1 AND
student9.sex=1 AND
student10.sex=1 AND
student11.sex=1 AND
student12.sex=1 and
student1.id<>student2.id and 
student1.id<>student3.id and 
student1.id<>student4.id and 
student1.id<>student5.id and 
student1.id<>student6.id and 
student1.id<>student7.id and 
student1.id<>student8.id and 
student1.id<>student9.id and
student1.id<>student10.id and
student1.id<>student11.id;
```

and the output error is

```
test-#  student1.id<>student7.id and 
test-#  student1.i
test-#  student1.id<>stude
test-#  student1.id<>stude
test-#  student1.id<>stude
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "student1"
LINE 132:  student1.id<>stude
       ^
```

Comment: If there is a maximum, it is more than 100.  The issue may be the maximum length of a query.

Comment: I agree with you that there may be maximum length of a query, but some viewpoints on web said there is no hard coded such number. a bit confused. anyone know how can I revise the source code to make it accepts long query? thanks.

Comment: PostgreSQL can parse queries that're megabytes in size, and have thousands of where clause predicates. There's something wrong with your query. (If it was length, you'd get an out of memory error). You'll need to show the query, PostgreSQL version, and **exact error message text**.

Comment: thanks, @Craig Ringer I have past the input and output in the question.

Comment: Adding the table definition for `student` would help us in reproducing this error. (BTW: what is the *purpose* of this bulky query ?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are much easier ways to do what you are trying to do.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: looks like an attempt at relational division to me ...

Comment: Unrelated but: you should stop using those outdated and error-prone implicit joins in the where clause and start using an explicit `JOIN` operator

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to figure out if you stopped using implicit joins? THey really are a SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've observed that pasting large amounts of data from the clipboard into psql running in an putty.exe session can cause it to get garbled, mostly characters getting dropped.

So I don't do that, I first paste it into the a file, and then `psql -f thefile.sql`

Presumably this is something about the readline library which psql program uses, because I can open vi in a putty session, put it in insert mode, and paste large amounts of data into that, without the dropping of characters.

Comment: You can also use the `\e` command inside psql to open "the current query buffer" in "your favourite editor" (i.e. the value of the `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variable).